# unusual image behaviours with float left and safari iPhone

Tags: css, html, safari

I have an image, which is floated left from some text:

```
        <ul class="row">
            <li class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="asset.svg" style="float:left;width:50px;height:50px;">
                <div>some text</div>
            </li>
            <...etc...>
```

The result I get from this (with .png as well) is attached:
[image: image resizing issue]

The width of the images seems to be dictated by the neighbouring div. Anyone know why this happens and how best to get around it?

Comment: Can you create an example using a StackSnippet or a site such as jsfiddle.net that shows the issue? There is obviously more CSS involved than that shown because your list is not styled as a normal list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: Properly close the IMG-tag with /> .
Second, does the div *some text* also have float:left ?
If the li has by example a width of 200px, and the img tag has a width of 50px, the div *some text* should have a width of 150px and float:left.

Hope that works for ya

Comment: `img` tags don't have a closing tag and so should not self-close with `/>` in HTML5. OP's code is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear, you should try and upload more details.

But you can try clear: both in your CSS code.